# Build and execute a dynamic list of observables with variables with Typescript and Angular

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am receiving an array that has `1..N` number of userIds. I am building a unique list of those Ids so that I only query the user info once:

```
const uniqueUserIds = [
  ...new Set(requests.map((item) => Number(item.userId))),
];
```

With this list of unique user Ids, I'd like to build a task list to go out and get each of them before moving on to the next block of code.

```
var tasks: Observable<User>[] = [];
uniqueUserIds.map((userId) => {
  tasks.push(this.getUserInfo(userId));
});
```

The `getUserInfo` method just returns an `Observable<User>`:

```
getUserInfo(userId: number) {
  return this.userServiceHttpClient.getUser(userId);
}
```

I've tried using the following, but none of my Observables are executing:

```
Promise.all(tasks).then((value) => {
  console.warn(value);
});
```

If I take the value and do a `.subscribe`, then the observable is executed.  Isn't there a way to take a list of Observables, all returning the same type, concatenate the results into an array, and then continue execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `Promise.all()` to await an array of Observables since it only works with Promises.

The `forkJoin` operator from RxJS was made exactly for this scenario :)

```
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs";

forkJoin(
  uniqueUserIds.map(id => this.getUserInfo(id))
).subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value)
})
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-hypatia-8v6xrz)

Comment: Any reason why the result from the forkJoin would be an array of arrays when executed in the browser?  VS Code tells me value is an array of Users, but when I inspect the object in Chrome, each value is a single value array of each user.

Comment: If you look at the console in the linked Sandbox, you will see that the returned array is not nested inside an array. Maybe the `getUserInfo` function is returning an array?